# Is it possible to set up a navigation property without the foreign key?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to have two (or more) navigation properties of the same type?

My model looks like this...

```cs
public class Agreement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? BuyerId { get; set; }
    public Guid? SellerId { get; set; }

    public AgreementInfo ByerAgreementInfo { get; set; }
    public AgreementInfo SellerAgreementInfo { get; set; }
}

public class AgreementInfo
{
    // PK is AgreementId and OwnerActorId combined.
    public int AgreementId { get; set; }
    public Guid OwnerActorId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

... and i'm trying to include the navigation properties by matching the AgreementId and the ByerId/SellerId...

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Agreement>().HasOne(x => x.ByerAgreementInfo).WithOne().HasForeignKey<Agreement>(x => new {x.Id, x.ProviderId});
modelBuilder.Entity<Agreement>().HasOne(x => x.SellerAgreementInfo).WithOne().HasForeignKey<Agreement>(x => new { x.Id, x.RequesterId });
```

> ... but this results in a circural dependecy.

Is there any way to include these properties without using a foreign key? Or is there another solution (except for adding an id-column to the info table) that allows me to use the info-table rows as navigation properties in the agreement class?

Comment: Check my answer. It should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than a handful of ways to achieve what you want. You could use *Data Annotations* with `InverseProperty` attribute on your child, `ForeignKey` attribute on your parent, or *fluent syntax* either way in your model builder. I tend to use attributes (*Data Annotations*) where I can (it's just my personal taste), I find it need to see the relationships in the actual mode itself (though others might not).

Using `ForeignKey` attribute:

```
public class Agreement
{
    ...

    [ForeignKey("ByerAgreementInfo ")]
    public int ByerAgreementInfoId { get; set; }
    public AgreementInfo ByerAgreementInfo { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SellerAgreementInfo ")]
    public int SellerAgreementInfoId { get; set; }
    public AgreementInfo SellerAgreementInfo { get; set; 
}
```

Using `InverseProperty` attribute:

```
public class AgreementInfo
{

    ...

    [InverseProperty("ByerAgreementInfo ")]
    public ICollection<Agreement> Sellers { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("SellerAgreementInfo ")]
    public ICollection<Agreement> Buyers { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to use *Fluent Syntax*, I believe the following will work (though I haven't used it for a while):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Agreement>()
    .HasOne(x => x.ByerAgreementInfo)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Agreement>(p => p.ByerAgreementInfoId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Agreement>()
    .HasOne(x => x.SellerAgreementInfo)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Agreement>(p => p.SellerAgreementInfoId);
```

<sub>***Note***: I'm think you may need the actual Id's in your model, though I can't remember.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

> ... but this results in a circural dependecy

Yes! It will. To overcome this you have to specify `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);` in your *Fluent API* configuration as follows but first you have to write your `Agreement` model class as follows too:

```
public class Agreement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? BuyerId { get; set; }
    public Guid? SellerId { get; set; }

    public int AgreementIdForBuyer { get; set; }
    public Guid OwnerActorIdForBuyer { get; set; }

    public int AgreementIdForSeller { get; set; }
    public Guid OwnerActorIdForSeller { get; set; }

    public AgreementInfo ByerAgreementInfo { get; set; }
    public AgreementInfo SellerAgreementInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Now in *Fluent API* configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Agreement>()
    .HasOne(x => x.ByerAgreementInfo)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Agreement>(p => new {p.AgreementIdForBuyer, p.AgreementIdForBuyer})
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); // <-- Here it is

modelBuilder.Entity<Agreement>()
    .HasOne(x => x.SellerAgreementInfo)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Agreement>(p => new {p.AgreementIdForSeller, p.OwnerActorIdForSeller})
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); // <-- Here it is
```